# Issues with Android Alternative Layouts in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin

I'm nearly flipping out. I'm trying to develop an app for several devices. The app should nearly look the same on all devices. I tried to create the layout like this:

- first i created the layout in the standard layout folder for an Samsung Galaxy S Plus device
  as that's the only hardware device I have
- the layout looks nice on the device
- after that I took one layout file and switched through the available virtual devices such as 2.7in QVGA...5.4in FWVGA...7in WSVGA...
- everytime when a switched the virtual device and the layout doesn´t look good I set the lock on qualifiers *Smallest screen width* and *Screen size*
- I make the changes so that the layout looks good for that specific virtual device and saved it.
- Xamarin creates an new folder like `layout-sw480dp-large`. In that folder I can see the recently changed file
- I have done this for all layout files in the standard layout folder and for all virtual devices.
- back in the standard layout folder I check all layout files with all devices. everything looks great.
- I have tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and the layout looks awful, textviews are not in the right place, image views are not in the right place etc.
- so back in Xamarin studio I checked all layout folders and each file. For example, in the folder `layout-sw480dp-xlarge` the layoutfile doesn't look good.
- I changed that file but then something weird happened: all files with the same name lying in a layout folder containing the qualifier `xlarge` are changed too (see the screenshot).
- I thought that changes in a layout folder don't cause changes in other folders. Is this a bug of Xamarin?

So I have 3 questions:

1. Is this weird behavoir of changing layoutfiles a bug of xamarin?
2. what is the best way to create layouts for different devices (please practical advises, i know the site of supporting multiple screens)
3. how can i create layout for Samsung S3 with Xamarin, how can i create a virtual device in xamarin which emulates the Samsung S3

Thank you very much.

[image: Screenshot of Xamarin Studio]

Answer (score 0):

i have informed xamarin about this issue. [link] (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13705).

The way i create layouts for several devices:

1. Create the layouts for in standard layout folder (i take a normal mdpi device)
2. when all layouts were created i copy them to another folder outside xamarin and rename .axml to .xml
3. i use eclipse to create alternative layouts in their specific folders
4. rename all files inside alternative layout folder from .xml to .axml
5. in xamarin studio create alternative layout folders and import specific files
6. run and test them on real hardware devices

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you open axml file in Xamarin Studio, you'll find two options graphical representation/ scrip. You can switch between layouts by changing alternate layouts, switching available near top left corner of axml file. 
For custom virtual device creation set same configuration as device which you want and create AVD